# Updating $scope values affects it's previous usage points

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Updating $scope values affects it's previous usage points.

After `addPhrase` call I use `sayPhrase` to update $scope

```
function PhrasesCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.trail = [0];

    $scope.addPhrase = function() {
        $scope.phrases.push({
            trail: $scope.trail
        });
    }

    $scope.sayPhrase = function(id) {
        // id = 1
        $scope.trail.push(id);
    }
}
```

Newly created Phrase have it's trail equal to [0], after sayPhrase call it becomes [0, 1]

After `$scope.trail.push(id);` my new element updates it's trail value.

How to keep used trail value away from changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because JS objects (and arrays) are passed by reference only.  When you push the `trail` into `phrases`, you are pushing the reference to the same array that is referenced by `$scope.trail`.

The easiest solution is to break the reference on `$scope.trail`, by creating a new array:

```
    $scope.addPhrase = function() {
        $scope.phrases.push({
            trail: $scope.trail
        });
        $scope.trail = [0]; // I assume the `0` is on purpose
    }
```

Now `$scope.trail` will start over every time `addPhrase()` is called.

---

Alternatively, if you need to keep the current contents of `trail`, you should copy the array into a new one. Angular conveniently provides a method just for this:

```
    $scope.addPhrase = function() {
        $scope.phrases.push({
            trail: angular.copy($scope.trail)
        });
    }
```

Comment: $scope.trail = [0]; // I assume the `0` is on purpose

I've tried this solution, but I need to save $scope.trail value, this code simply kills it.

Comment: Also, an alternative to using `angular.copy` (which is a deep copy) is to do something like `var t = []; t.concat($scope.trail);` and then `trail: t` in your object.